How do I use i18n:data (Zope/TAL)
I can't figure out how i18n:data is supposed to work in a Zope Page Template. I found no examples in the documentation and only the following code snippets in the zope/tal tests:
<span i18n:data="here/currentTime"
      i18n:translate="timefmt">2:32 pm</span>

and
<div i18n:translate="">At the tone the time will be
<span i18n:data="here/currentTime"
      i18n:translate="timefmt"
      i18n:name="time">2:32 pm</span>... beep!</div>

It seems clear that the msgid is "timefmt", but what has to be written in the msgstr?
msgid "timefmt"
msgstr "%H:%M"

This displays the formatting string. I also tried ${%H:%M} to no avail.
